# What is a good app for either the iPhone or Apple Watch to track the exercises I do in the gym?

Tags: ios, fitness

When I worked out in the gym with a trainer thousands of years ago, she kept a notebook of each exercise (like what pieces of equipment) and the weight and perhaps some other stuff like she would put little marks to indicate to increase the weight next week.

I've recently started back in the gym but I'm just doing it by myself.  Is there an app on the iPhone that would replace my trainer's notebook?

If it hooked up to my Apple Watch, that would be a plus.

Comment: I build my programs in google sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a cornucopia of these available in the App Store:

- [Gymatic](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gymatic-workout-tracker/id1036069872)
- [Fitbod](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fitbod-weight-lifting-workout/id1041517543)
- [Strong Workout Tracker](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/strong-workout-tracker-gym-log/id464254577)
- [Gymaholic](https://www.gymaholic.me/)
- [Progression](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/progression-get-strong/id1090687896)
- [Intensity](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/intensity-workout-journal/id1047407323)

A fair few sync with Apple Health and have Apple Watch apps. Quite a few of them seem to be freemium with quite expensive monthly subscription plans, so beware.

Comment: It would have been better if you said a few words about them. That is the point of the question. To recommend one.